# Showing all the blobs from multiple storage containers in Azure using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I am trying to list all the blobs from various containers that i have in an Azure storage account using powershell
So i run the below commands :

```
$storageAccountName = "contoso"
$resourceGroup = "Contoso-Rg"
$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccountName).Value[0]
$context=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountkey
$containerName =   Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $context

$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccountName

$ctx = $storageAccount.Context

$containerName | ForEach-Object { Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $_ -Context $ctx }
```

When i run the last command it throws me the error as shown in the screenshot. Any idea what i am doing wrong and how to fix this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing `$_` to '-contianer' flag you need to pass `$_.Name` to container parameter  in foreach-object.

Posting making the above changes to the shared script we are able to pull all the bolbs inside the container.

**Here is the modified script :**

```
$storageAccountName = "<strgAccountName>"
$resourceGroup = "<rgName>"

$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccountName).Value[0]
$context=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountkey

$containerName =   Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $context

$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccountName

$containerName | ForEach-Object { Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $_.Name -Context $context }
```

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

[image]